# Pass function to Pug template to be used via callback in Javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm trying to pass a function (timeAgo module) to my Pug template to be used in my frontend Javascript during a callback.

However no combination of methods I try can get the module to work during a callback. If I use it while I compile the frontend it works fine of course, but I can't load the module as a function in a script tag such that I can use it again.

So:

`p.balance-text #{timeAgo.format(new Date(story.publishedAt))}`

Works fine, but how can I do something like:

```
script. 
  // this allows me to use it to format dates received via an AJAX request
  var  timeAgo = #{timeAgo}
```

I've also tried things like using JSON.stringify to pass it to the frontend but nothing seems to work. Is it possible with pug? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

You are generating HTML source code. So everything needs to be able to be cast to a string.

> I've also tried things like using JSON.stringify

This is also why JSON doesn't have a function data type.

Generate a `<script>` element with a `src` attribute that loads the module in a static file. (If it is an ES6 module, then either use `<script type="module">` and `import` it instead, or use Webpack).

Comment: Yup I was slowly arriving at this conclusion, thanks for clearing any doubt for me.